# Как выровнять всё по-центру так, что бы содержимое занимало весь блок (картинку)?

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.list {
    background: url(../Eclipse/image/Bg2.png) top no-repeat;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.listText {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5%;
}
.listGray {
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    color: #333333;
}
.listRed {
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    color: #cb0e16;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
}
.list input {
    background-image: url(../Eclipse/image/input.png);
    background-size: 3% 30%;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 15px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 2% 8%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.705);
    font-family: RobotoLight;
}
.list button {
    background-color: #cb0e16;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: RobotoRegular;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: 2% 8% 2% 8%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
                    <div class="listText">
                        <p class="listGray">Нужен срочный перевод контракта или делового письма? Переговоры с иностранными партнерами 
                            перенесли на сегодняшний вечер, а под рукой нет переводчика?
                        </p>
                        <p class="listRed">Решите задачу сейчас:</p>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите имя:">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон:">
                        <button>Нужен срочный перевод</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Вы же недавно опубликовали вопрос с тем же самым кодом, но там было всё нормально))

Comment: нет, было хуже, всё вылазило, щас внутри листика но выровнять нормально не могу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как поместить информацию в картинку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001412/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Зачем вы создаете дубликат вопроса?

Comment: Опишите ваш вопрос более конкретно, что не получается, какое поведение вы ожидаете

Comment: текст, импуты и кнопка должны занять весь блок, они должны быть в центре этого блока

Comment: Вашу картинку здесь не видно, залейте ее на хостинг и укажите в коде ссылку

Answer (score 1):

```css
.list {
  background: url(../Eclipse/image/Bg2.png) top no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
}

.listText {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
}

.listGray {
  font-family: RobotoLight;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  color: #333333;
}

.listRed {
  font-family: RobotoLight;
  color: #cb0e16;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
}

.list input {
  background-image: url(../Eclipse/image/input.png);
  background-size: 3% 30%;
  background-color: white;
  background-position: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 2% 8%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.705);
  font-family: RobotoLight;
}

.list button {
  background-color: #cb0e16;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: RobotoRegular;
  font-size: 1vw;
  padding: 2% 8% 2% 8%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="listText">
    <p class="listGray">Нужен срочный перевод контракта или делового письма? Переговоры с иностранными партнерами перенесли на сегодняшний вечер, а под рукой нет переводчика?
    </p>
    <p class="listRed">Решите задачу сейчас:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите имя:">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон:">
    <button>Нужен срочный перевод</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Только размер шрифтам более читабельный задайте)